# How to get a list of all map keys in elixir

Tags: elixir

Is there a way in elixir to get all of the map keys similar to `array_keys` in PHP? I have been searching but cannot seem to find a way.

Or is there another way to get unique values? I am assigning names to keys in the map with a value of `1` to get only distinct values. Then I would like to get the keys to only retrieve the unique values.

I am using this code to create my map:

```
names = Enum.reduce lines, %{}, fn line, acc ->
  Map.put(acc, line.name, 1)
end
```

For example, I have two lines with `line.name` as test. I would want the end result to return just test. Or if they are different return them separately, then use something like `enum.join` to combine them

```
Enum.join(names, " - ")
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`Map.keys/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#keys/1):

```
map = %{a: 1, b: 2}
Map.keys(map)
#=> [:a, :b]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run iex and type TAB after a module name, it will list out all the functions the module exports.

> iex> h Map.\'TAB\'
>
> iex(1)> h Map.keys
>
> ```
>                              def keys(map)
> ```
>
> Returns all keys from map.
>
> ### Examples
>
> ```
> iex> Map.keys(%{a: 1, b: 2})
> [:a, :b]
> ```

You might want to look into the documentation for `MapSet`, it's more or less what you are doing with some additional helpful methods.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it using this

```
Enum.uniq(Enum.map(lines, fn line -> line.name end))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the answers given provide an ultimate solution on how to get `Map`’s keys, after reading the whole question I came to conclusion you somehow do it wrong from the scratch.

First of all, the way you produce map is IMHO not the most readable one. The intent is not clear enough. Let’s start with the uniqueness:

```
lines = [%{name: "test", a: 42},
         %{name: "test", b: 42},
         %{name: "foo"}]
#⇒ [%{a: 42, name: "test"},
#   %{b: 42, name: "test"},
#   %{name: "foo"}]
Enum.map(lines, & &1.name)
#⇒ ["test", "test", "foo"]
```

Nearly what we need. Let’s uniq them:

```
lines |> Enum.map(& &1.name) |> Enum.uniq
#⇒ ["test", "foo"]
```

Cool. Let’s now produce a map:

```
lines
|> Enum.map(& &1.name)
|> IO.inspect      #⇒ ["test", "test", "foo"]
|> Enum.uniq
|> IO.inspect      #⇒ ["test", "foo"]
|> Enum.zip(Stream.cycle [1])
|> IO.inspect      #⇒ [{"test", 1}, {"foo", 1}]
|> Enum.into(%{})  #⇒ %{"foo" => 1, "test" => 1}
```

In my opinion, this is way more readable, elixirish and (for many duplicates) efficient. Get rid of `IO.inspect` in the production code, of course.